# i am building a project on online file explorer, whenever i try to launch app to local host its says "du command not recognised"

Tags: javascript

```js
const {execSync} = require('child_process');

try{
    const result = execSync(`du -sh "\Users\hites\Downloads\1.1 Node Project1 - File Explorer.zip (1)\Node Project1 - File Explorer"`).toString();
    console.log(result);
}catch(err){
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
```

output:::

```sh
'du' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:child_process:903
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: du -sh "C:\Users\hites\Downloads\1.1 Node Project1 - File Explorer.zip (1)\Node Project1 - File Explorer\static\code"
'du' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:826:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:900:15)
    at calculateSizeD (C:\Users\hites\Downloads\1.1 Node Project1 - File Explorer.zip (1)\Node Project1 - File Explorer\lib\calculateSizeD.js:8:27)
    at C:\Users\hites\Downloads\1.1 Node Project1 - File Explorer.zip (1)\Node Project1 - File Explorer\lib\mainContent.js:55:57
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at buildMainContent (C:\Users\hites\Downloads\1.1 Node Project1 - File Explorer.zip (1)\Node Project1 - File Explorer\lib\mainContent.js:31:11)
    at Server.respond (C:\Users\hites\Downloads\1.1 Node Project1 - File Explorer.zip (1)\Node Project1 - File Explorer\lib\respond.js:72:29)
    at Server.emit (node:events:390:28)
```

Comment: What OS are you using to run that program?

Comment: Make sure you have the path to your `du` executable in the system path or use a full path to it in your command

Comment: i am using windows....vs code.

Comment: can you please help me to have a path du in system path

Comment: As far as I know, the `du` command exists in unix environment. Windows does not have `du` command ready to be executed from command prompt by default. Check out this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/298876/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-the-unix-du-command) if you are looking for the alternative or way to set it up.

Comment: can you just run this du comand from sheel ?

Comment: is there any way that i can run du command through vs code terminal? because i have seen it in youtube video

Answer (score 0):

To get this running, you can simply run that in wsl (Windows Subsystem for Linux) assuming you have that installed and assuming that the version of wsl/linux you use with that has du. Worked for me. You would have to revise your path so you're using /mnt/c/... instead of C:\...

Comment: i got it thanks for you reply....i managed to solve this issue by simply switch to Git bash terminal replacing windows or powershell terminal... i am able to run du command right from vs code terminal